# How does a photon travel through an electron cloud?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, photon-emission

We all know that the exact position and exact velocity of an electron in an atom cannot be determined simultaneously, as per the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. We only talk about the probability of finding the electron at different points in the atom. 
So how does a photon travel through the outermost electron cloud without interacting with electrons there, and excite an inner electron?

Comment: The photon is delocalised and doesn't have an exact position either. Your image of a photon having to barge its way past the outer electrons to get to inner ones is misleading. A photon will typically be delocalised over distances much, much larger the size of the atom, so the probability distribution of the photon within the atom is roughly constant.

Comment: "....so the probability distribution of the photon within the atom is roughly constant." okay, but my question is that how inner electron can absorb a photon which is delocalised over the atom?